# make: Nothing to be done for `default' JAVA

Tags: java, makefile

There are several questions with this title and I looked over them but did not find a solution. I am trying to create a MakeFile for my java project so that the prof can run it easily in unix environment. Here is the content of my makefile file:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
JVM= java

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
     DivisorStorage.java\
     countingNumberOfDivisorsRunnable.java\
     HighestDivisor.java\

MAIN = HighestDivisor

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

run: classes
      $(JVM) $(MAIN)

clean:
      $(RM) *.class
```

and then i am tying "make -f makefile" but this error comes up "make: Nothing to be done for `default'" 
am i even using the right command to run the program?"make -f makefile"

Any help is appreciated! Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Try `make clean`, and then `make`.

Comment: So it actually worked and went like: javac -g DivisorStorage.java
javac -g countingNumberOfDivisorsRunnable.java       which are two of my classes. But nothing else happened? Isn't supposed to run my application?

Comment: Make run. The default target builds. If there is nothing to build...

Comment: Wow it worked thank you so much @ElliottFrisch

Comment: FWIW, Makefiles aren't considered particularly "idiomatic" for Java. Consider using a Java build tool like Ant or Gradle.